# C# DI container loading without errors but not reading from JSON config file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following C#.NET/Visual Studio project directory structure:

```
C:\Users\myuser\repos\myapp\MyApp\
    bin/
    obj/
    MyConfig.cs
    myconfig.json
    Program.cs
```

Where `myconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "SerialKey": "12345"
}
```

And where `MyConfig.cs` is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyConfig
{
    public string SerialKey { get; set; }
}
```

And where `Program.cs` is:

```
namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("myconfig.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            // load app settings configs
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .Configure<MyConfig>(options => configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Bind(options))
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var myConfig = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyConfig>>().Value;
            
            Console.WriteLine("serial key is: " + myConfig.SerialKey)

            // do something
            DoSomething();

        }
    }
}
```

When this runs, I get no errors, but the `myConfig.SerialKey` field is `null` (I can verify by setting a breakpoint and running in Debugger mode). So either my code setup is incorrect or I'm not placing the JSON file in the right location. **Anybody see where I'm going awry?**

Please include any Package Manage Console commands (`dotnet add ...`) if they are needed.

Comment: There's no "MyConfig" section in myconfig.json. Bind to the root instead.

Comment: Would love to know what that code would look like. Maybe `options => configuration.GetSection("{}")`?

Comment: `.Configure<MyConfig>(options => configuration.Bind(options))`

Comment: Appreciate the help but its still not working, `myConfig.SerialKey` is still null at runtime. Is `myconfig.json` in the wrong location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("myconfig.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
var myconfig = configuration.Get<MyConfig>();
Console.WriteLine(myconfig.SerialKey);
```

myconfig.json  (path:...\bin\Debug\net8.0)

```
{
  "SerialKey": "12345"
}
```

Test output
[image]